# What is the meaning of "Building wheel for xxx" when I use pip install package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I running the command `pip install allennlp`, the output looks below. What is the meaning of `Building wheel for xxx`? What is the action behind  `Building wheel for xxx`?

```
Building wheel for jsonnet (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/xu/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/f0/47/51/a178b15274ed0db775a1ae9c799ce31e511609c3ab75a7dec5
  Building wheel for nltk (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/xu/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/97/8a/10/d646015f33c525688e91986c4544c68019b19a473cb33d3b55
  Building wheel for parsimonious (setup.py) ... done
```

I've done some search and it seems `wheel` is a kind of files that help pip to set up the package, but I still have not a clear understanding. I know this question might be a silly question, it would be good to know the answer though.

Comment: create a distribution package and install in system. [here is link to learn](https://pythonwheels.com/)

Comment: @prashantrana Thanks for the links. It does explain what `wheel` is. But I also want to know what is the action behind  `Building wheel for xxx`.

Comment: how it process then you need to read wheel documentation,  why we create wheel , it's just beacuse when a developer create a package let's say numpy (which is code in c, python) and wants it to distribute and let other to use in there system, so then they create a wheel package ( just like .exe, contains all info regarding the what requre this pacakkage to run , other package, system requirement, python version etc ) and when do `pip install <wheel package` with that help , it is stored in `site package` in python so that when  we use `import <wheel xxx>` it got imported in our code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you have already caught up with documentation on:

- The [Wheel Packaging format](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) and what the .whl file contains
- [Building a .whl file](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/27/python-on-wheels/)
- [Installing from Pypi](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#source-distributions-vs-wheels)

Running `pip install allennlp` with `-vvv` offers more insights related to your specific question:

```
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/kh/1cpkyp_535jg856yrdnql0rw0000gn/T/pip-install-leyfrduz

...

Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/kh/1cpkyp_535jg856yrdnql0rw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-s1uhiijv
Building wheel for jsonnet (setup.py) ...   Destination directory: /private/var/folders/kh/1cpkyp_535jg856yrdnql0rw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-s1uhiijv
Running command /Users/subhashb/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/envs/test-env-dev/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kh/1cpkyp_535jg856yrdnql0rw0000gn/T/pip-install-leyfrduz/jsonnet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/kh/1cpkyp_535jg856yrdnql0rw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-s1uhiijv --python-tag cp37
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
c++ -c -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -std=c++0x -fPIC -Iinclude -Ithird_party/md5 -Ithird_party/json core/desugarer.cpp -o core/desugarer.o
core/desugarer.cpp:406:67: warning: unused parameter 'obj_level' [-Wunused-parameter]
    AST* makeArrayComprehension(ArrayComprehension *ast, unsigned obj_level) {

...

writing manifest file 'jsonnet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying jsonnet.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel/jsonnet-0.12.1-py3.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
adding license file "LICENSE" (matched pattern "LICEN[CS]E*")
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel/jsonnet-0.12.1.dist-info/WHEEL
creating '/private/var/folders/kh/1cpkyp_535jg856yrdnql0rw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-s1uhiijv/jsonnet-0.12.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel' to it
adding '_jsonnet.cpython-37m-darwin.so'
adding 'jsonnet-0.12.1.dist-info/LICENSE'
adding 'jsonnet-0.12.1.dist-info/METADATA'
adding 'jsonnet-0.12.1.dist-info/WHEEL'
adding 'jsonnet-0.12.1.dist-info/top_level.txt'
adding 'jsonnet-0.12.1.dist-info/RECORD'
removing build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel
done
```

The pip package code that makes this beautiful process run is at [github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/wheel.py#L948). And it eventually ends up making a call to `jsonnet`'s [Makefile](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/wheel.py#L948) to "build" the wheel

In short, picking the example of `jsonnet`, running `pip install jsonnet` does the following:

- downloads the jsonnet.tar.gz to a local temporary folder
- invokes a `c++` command to compile .cpp files
- builds `_jsonnet.cpython-37m-darwin.so` (which is the correct library format for my Mac OS machine)
- records the wheel distribution info in `jsonnet-0.12.1.dist-info` (typically present in your virtual env)

This flow is for `jsonnet`, and it happens to be slightly complicated because jsonnet is ultimatly a C extension. But regular python packages will just have the source file(s) downloaded and installed in the virtualenv. You can walk the same path to understand what happens behind any package.